# Using Emacs as a server and opening only one window exactly, which should be maximized

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I'd like to run my Emacs in daemon mode, and then use `emacsclient` to actually display things. However, if I run `emacsclient filename`, it shows up in the terminal, which isn't what I want; I instead have to pass it the `-c` option.

However, that option always creates a new frame, which isn't what I want - I'd rather just have *one* frame, and have stuff open in a new buffer in the same frame if it already exists; otherwise, it should make me a new frame. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Additionally, I want that one frame to be maximized, which I usually achieve my starting Emacs with the `-mm` option; how would I ensure that a frame made by `emacsclient` is also maximized?

Comment: I'm not sure about your initial call to `emacsclient` (ie, before you've opened your first frame), but when there's a graphical frame already open, `emacsclient filename` visits `filename` in the existing frame (at least for me).  Is it *always* the case that it opens in terminal for you, or just when you have no existing graphical frame?

Comment: @Dan: Only when I have no existing frame. Is there any way to force it to use a frame by default instead of the terminal? Basically, I would like to have a command which a) opens a frame if there isn't one; and b) if there is a frame, opens the document in the same frame in a new buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For having every new frame maximized, you could add this to your .emacs:

```
(modify-all-frames-parameters '((fullscreen . maximized))))
```

Comment: Isn't `modify-all-frames-parameters` a one shot deal for whatever frame(s) is/are open at the moment?  Perhaps you were thinking of `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist . . .`?  Here is a link to some code I use for OSX and Windows to control the precise frame size using pixels -- it may require a more recent or developer build of Emacs though:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18711628/2112489

Comment: `modify-all-frames-parameters` (at least in my emacs version, 24.3) have effect in the frames yet to be created.

Answer (score 5):

The following script does the following:

- start Emacs server if necessary
- if there are no open frames, open a new one
- open the given file(s) in the current frame

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Selected options for "emacsclient"
#
# -c          Create a new frame instead of trying to use the current
#             Emacs frame.
#
# -e          Evaluate the FILE arguments as ELisp expressions.
#
# -n          Don't wait for the server to return.
#
# -t          Open a new Emacs frame on the current terminal.
#
# Note that the "-t" and "-n" options are contradictory: "-t" says to
# take control of the current text terminal to create a new client frame,
# while "-n" says not to take control of the text terminal.  If you
# supply both options, Emacs visits the specified files(s) in an existing
# frame rather than a new client frame, negating the effect of "-t".

# check whether an Emacs server is already running
pgrep -l "^emacs$" > /dev/null

# otherwise, start Emacs server daemon
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    emacs --daemon
fi

# return a list of all frames on $DISPLAY
emacsclient -e "(frames-on-display-list \"$DISPLAY\")" &>/dev/null

# open frames detected, so open files in current frame
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    emacsclient -n -t "$@"
# no open frames detected, so open new frame
else
    emacsclient -n -c "$@"
fi
```

*Edit: fixed expansion of positional arguments (2017-12-31).*

Comment: This works fine for terminal emacs. If you want to use the GUI emacs instead, change the line from `emacsclient -n -t $*` to `emacsclient -n -a emacs $*`

Comment: @Jounathaen Both work, so this doesn't change anything for me (Emacs 24.5). But it might be different for other Emacs versions...

Answer (score 1):

Is your DISPLAY env set in the terminal where you're running emacsclient? Because the behavior you request should be the default (the behavior of reusing existing frames, I mean).

Comment: When I execute ``echo $DISPLAY``, I get the output ``:0``