# How to remove toolbar in .emacs in windows WITHOUT losing windows maximized state?

Tags: windows, emacs

When I try to disable the toolbar in my .emacs using the following command :

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(tool-bar-mode nil)
)
```

or (UPDATE) following :

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

the window's maximum size is reduced to only a part of the screen.

It even isn't in 'restored window size modus', but it really thinks it is maximized, so maximizing it again (using a w32-send command for example) has no effect.

If I apply the same command after starting up in lisp-interatction mode, this behaviour does not occur.

UPDATE : 
VERY RELATED  : [How to maximize Emacs on Windows at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815239/how-to-maximize-emacs-on-windows-at-startup)

Although this question is about removing toolbars and the other about maximizing state, it turns out the question is about the very same issue : it's the toolbar there too that is preventing the user to maximze his window.

Comment: which version of emacs, and on which platform.?

Comment: windows (as mentioned both int the title and a tag) and 23.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bug, please report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a bug.  However an easy wokaround is supplied here :

[How to maximize Emacs on Windows at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815239/how-to-maximize-emacs-on-windows-at-startup)

kenny-jensen

for convenience, I repeat it here :

```
(w32-send-sys-command #xf030)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook (lambda () (tool-bar-mode -1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

to disable a minor mode give negative argument

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

UPDATE:
At least on linux, it doesn't shrink